# Assigning a table to innerHtml breaks web site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have build a result page for a calculation. It's basically a CSS-grid in a DIV. The grid has three columns. In each column there are tiles (divs) which contain tables (which show the results).

In JavaScript I calculate the result tables and assign them to the tables. There is an outermost div where I set display to "table".

Here is the problem: Some browsers on some computers present a long empty page. At the very end I can see a bit of tables, the rest is clipped.

This may happen at the beginning where build the page or when I replace a table by a newly calculated table.

For now I found an unsatisfying work around:
Before any assignments to div.innerHtml I set display of the outermost div to none. After the assignments I set it back to table after a setTimeout of 0.5 sec. Then the page is built properly.

It looks like that after the assignments some time is needed to build the internal DOM structure but I don't know any event to wait for.

Here is the essence of the html structure:

```
<div style="display: table">
  <div style="display: grid; grid-template-areas: 'left center right';">
    <div style="grid-area: left">
      <div id="result_table0"></div>
      <div id="result_table1"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="grid-area: center">
      <div id="result_table2"></div>
      <div id="result_table3"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="grid-area: right">
      <div id="result_table4"></div>
      <div id="result_table5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript assignments of the tables looks similar like that:

```
// calculation of the table
let my_result_table = '<table><tr><td>xxx</td><td>yyy</td></tr></table>';

// assignment to the div
document.getElementById('result_table0').innerHTML = my_result_table;
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: is there a need for display table?  if you use that then it's in effect turning that tag into a table tag so anything but a display table-row child will cause issues

Comment: `innerHtml` doesn’t exist. You mean [`innerHTML`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and is not `type="module"`? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: Also id attribute values must be **unique**. There can be only one "result_table0".

Comment: My understanding of `display: table` css is that it is used in conjunction with `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` for child and grand-child elements respectively. You seem to be combining `display: table` with `grid` display items and I'm not sure this approach will work reliably. I would either define a grid for the table and its immediate descendents (equivalent to table rows) or stick with `table`, `table-row` and `table-data` for the outer div and its descendents.

Comment: My mistake in this post: I corrected the ids. Plus innerHTML.

Comment: I found display: table useful because it made everything inside as small as necessary. display: block uses the whole page width. I made this decision long time ago and have never questioned it. Now I realized that this strange effect is not happening when I use  display: block. So the problem is solved and I have to deal with the width issue in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

**Some pointers on using css `display: table/table-row/table-cell` or `display: grid` to render table-like structures in html**

I've prepared some examples in the following snippet to show how css `table` and `grid` can be used.

`display: table` can be applied to an outer container, its children elements (typically intended as 'rows' in a normal `<table><tr><td>...` structure) are given the style attribute `display: table-row`. In turn the children of the rows (grandchildren of the table, analagous to `td` elements in regular `table` parlance) are given the style attribute `display: table-cells`.

In some examples below, I show how the normal hierarchy can be changed, for example to display 'rows' side by side or 'cells' above-and-below each other.

I also include a simple effective grid styling where cells can be sized very easily with short simple grid-templates.

Generally speaking, use one or the other as the `table` options style the element they are attached to while `grid` specifies how child items will be placed. Grid has an added advantage of allowing every placed item to be set to different display types, allowing a grid item to be a grid container, a flex-box or whatever best suits styling of that item. Grid is also very easy to size if column and row `templates` are included for the `grid` container.

```css
/* rules for table div, its children (rows) and its granchildren (cells)*/

.table {
  display: table;
}
.table>div {
  display: table-row;
}
.table>div>div {
  display: table-cell;
}


div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width:30px;
  min-height:10px
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>table, table-row, table-cell values of style display attribute </h2>
<p>1) divs formatted using display: [table/table-row/table-cell] set using inline style attributes </p>
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row;">
      <div style="display: table-cell;">1</div>
      <div style="display: table-cell;">2</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
      <div style="display: table-cell;">3</div>
      <div style="display: table-cell;">4</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
      <div style="display: table-cell;">5</div>
      <div style="display: table-cell;">6</div>
    </div>    
</div>

<p>2) divs formatted using display: [table/table-row/table-cell] set using stylesheet css rules applied to class attribute of outer div and its descendents </p>
<div class="table">
    <div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
    </div>    
</div>


<h2>display: grid example: </h2>
<p>divs formatted using display: grid with optional cell sizing within the row and column templates.</p>
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-rows: 30px 50px 30px; width: 50%;">
    <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;">
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;">
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
    </div>
    
</div>

<h2> display: table/table-cell to place 'rows' side-by-side</h2>
<p>This example uses display: table-cell for both the children and grand-children of the table. It allows the children (normally considered rows) to be placed side-by-side. table-cells make the div behave as an inline-block</p>
<div style="display: table">

    <div style="display: table-cell">
      <div style="display: table-cell">1</div>
      <div style="display: table-cell">2</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">
      <div style="display: table-cell">3</div>
      <div style="display: table-cell">4</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">
      <div style="display: table-cell">5</div>
      <div style="display: table-cell">6</div>
    </div>

</div>

<h2>putting table-rows inside  (some) table-cells</h2>
<p>This example applies table-cell to the children of the table (normally considered rows) to place them side-by side. The grandchildren with display set to table-cell are placed side-by-side within the side-by-side children except for the middle child which has its children styled as table-rows (forcing them onto separate lines). Table-rows gives an inline-block type display to divs.</p>

<div style="display: table">

    <div style="display: table-cell">
      <div style="display: table-cell">1</div>
      <div style="display: table-cell">2</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">
      <div style="display: table-row">3</div>
      <div style="display: table-row">4</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">
      <div style="display: table-cell">5</div>
      <div style="display: table-cell">6</div>
    </div>

</div>

<h2>above-and-below table-rows inside table-cells</h2>
<p>The final example treats the children (usually rows) as table-cells, displaying them side-by-side but its children are displayed as table-rows, causing them to stack on top of each other </p>
<div style="display: table">

    <div style="display: table-cell">
      <div style="display: table-row">1</div>
      <div style="display: table-row">2</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">
      <div style="display: table-row">3</div>
      <div style="display: table-row">4</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">
      <div style="display: table-row">5</div>
      <div style="display: table-row">6</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Great, now I know about display:table.
I tried it and it worked in a way that the result was shown. However, my real application is not as homogenous as the example I stated. I basically need three columns, there are 2-3-3 tiles (for now, may change in future) in the columns, each tile is different in size. This somehow resulted in column 2 and 3 having a bit of a vertical offset.

So I kept the grid and set the outermost div to display:flex which makes it as small as possible. That's perfect now.

Comment: I also tried to put the grid into three times wrapper: table -- table-row -- table-cell. But then I had the same problem with sometimes not having rendered the web page (i.e.: win10/Firefox while it's working mostly with GNU/Linux/Firefox).

Comment: How did you try specifying the grid inside the table-cell? `table-cell` is a `display` attribute value affecting the positioning of *the element is is applied to* wheras `grid` is a `display` attribute value affecting the positioning of *the contents of the element it is applied to*. So, the table element cannot have both `table-cell` and `grid` applied to its css `display` property. I would be inclined to use grid for most of the layout and try the table family on the inner-most table.

Comment: I tried two things:
.) 
`<div style="display: table">
<div style="display: table-row">
<div style="display: table-cell">
<div style="display: grid">
3 divs as three columns`
which resulted in not getting rendered correctly.

.) I omitted the first three divs and Instead of the <div style="display: grid"> I wrote the following:
`<div style="display: table">
<div style="display: table-row">
<div style="display: table-cell"> x 3`
where I got column 2 and 3 with a slight vertical offset which I couldn't explain.

Comment: Basically  I did it the way you suggested. I left the grid outside (with a flex-div-wrapping to make it as small as possible) and then inside there are the tables (where I used the old style <table> but I don't see a reason to change it to display: table).

Comment: ok, sounds like progress. Is it now rendering as you wanted?

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be solved. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use display: flex (or block) instead of display: table .

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You made me questioning the obvious.